# Rails 3 and Twilio to do phone verification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twilio, verification, phone-call

I am building an app in Rails 3, using twilio to verify a businesses existance. Basically, when you create a new buisiness I randomly generate a 6 digit number and then call the business phone number with this verification code and the user needs to enter it back in the system to finish the signup process.  I am having trouble finding any relevant examples as to how to get this set up.  I've found [this](http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/appointment-reminder), but it seems horribly outdated and doesn't work with Rails 3 seemingly. The documentation for the [twilio-rb gem](https://github.com/stevegraham/twilio-rb) is confusing as well.

Does anyone know of any examples or have any code samples that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you clarify if you're after a whole app or is there a particular part of the process you need help with, e.g., Twiml to read the DTMF, how to make the call from Rails, or what a controller might look like that responds to Twilio calls, or ...?

Comment: i am the author of the twilio-rb gem. you can add me on skype if you have any questions. i would also appreciate any feedback you have on how i could improve the docs/readme! skype id: sjtg85

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in the comment on your question itself, I am the author of the twilio-rb gem you mention. Off the top of my head, I would implement a verifications resource that you post a telephone number to.

```
POST /verifications.voice { telephone_number: '+12125551234' }
```

In the create action use `Twilio::Call.create` to create a new call with Twilio

```
def create
  @verification = Verification.new params[:verification]

  if @verification.save
    Twilio::Call.create to: @verification.telephone_number, 
      from: YOUR_CALLER_ID, url: verification_url(@verification, format: :voice)
    # 201 created and return verification code etc
  else
    # Handle errors
  end
end
```

You will also want to rescue any API errors that twilio-rb might raise. The url refers to the show action of the verification resource instance. Twilio will then dial the supplied telephone number, and when the call is connected will request the url, e.g. `GET /verifications/1.voice` so you'll need a show view that asks for the verification code and collects the digits with the [`<Gather>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather):

```
res.gather num_digits: 4, action: twilio_hack_verification_url(@verification, :format => :voice), method: 'POST' do |form|
  form.say 'Please enter the your 4 digit verification code'
end
```

Since Twilio currently does not implement the PUT verb, you'll to add a member to your resource

```
resources :verifications do
  member { post 'twilio_hack' }
end
```

Then in your controller update the object with the user input:

```
def twilio_hack
  @verification = Verification.find(params[:id]).tap do |v|
    v.user_input params['Digits']
    v.save
  end

  if @verification.confirmed?
    # handle success
  else
    # handle failure
  end

end
```

Finally in your model you'll need code that generates the verification code, and verifies if it is confirmed

```
class Verification < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save   -> { self[:confirmed] = true if user_input == verification_code }, if: user_input
  before_create -> { self[:verification_code] = rand.to_s[2..5] }
end
```

This is all untested and off the top of my head with about 2 minutes thought, but it should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

When you wish to verify a Business:

- Generate a verification code.
- Use the Twilio REST API to initiate an outbound call, passing a URL for a callback to a controller which will handle the verification logic. Docs at Twilio are [here](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making_calls) and an example is [here](http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/appointment-reminder).
- This means that you need to pass the verification code into your controller via the callback URL. Use a non-resourceful route with a bound parameter. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes).

Write a controller that handles the call and processes the verification:

- Emit TwiML that challenges the user to enter the verification code. I have found using Nokogiri to build the TwiML myself to be the most straightforward approach. (See the method phone_greeting in this simple app I wrote: [here](https://github.com/joncooper/fwdphone/blob/master/twiml.rb).)
- If it's correct, flag the Business as verified, congratulate the user, and hang up.
- If not, loop.

Hopefully that's enough information to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Twilio's Outgoing Caller IDs to help solve this problem?

When calling Twilio over REST  to add a new caller id to your account, Twilio will return a 6 digit verification code (property ValidationCode) for you to display in your UI, and then Twilio will automatically call the number and prompt for the code.  When the user verifies the number over the phone, their number will be added to your account's caller ids.  You can then query Twilio for their phone number over REST (parameter PhoneNumber) to ensure the verification was successful.

See here for documentation:

Add a caller id: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids#list-post

Find a caller id: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids#list

Comment: This isn't a solution to the OP's problem.